How can I convert a string to "unix mode bits" u32 in rust
I am trying to convert a string value (taken from environment variables) to unix mode bits used in the std::fs::Permissions::from_mode() method. I haven't found much on the subject and am hoping this is possible.
I have tried parsing to u32 but that fails with an error

ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }

Code example:
#[test]
fn can_convert_string_to_permissions() {
  let string_mode: &str = "0x666";
  let u32_mode: u32 = 0x666;

  // fails with error: called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }
  let mode: u32 = string_mode.to_string().parse().unwrap();

  assert_eq!(mode, u32_mode);
}

How can I convert a string representation of the "mode" to the u32 version that the Permissions struct is expecting?

For one thing, permissions are normally octal digits and not hexadecimal, so 0x is either wrong or just weird. You'll see the linked documentation uses 0o644 as an example.

A second issue will be that FromStr has no way to take a base, so for numbers it only handles base10 conversions from undecorated numbers.
